# Binding HttpPostedFileBase using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, model-binding

I have a form which binds a model and a file upload using the default binder for HttpPostedFileBase.

This works fine when using Html.BeginForm(). However, I wanted to perform the same action using AJAX so I replaced this with Ajax.BeginForm() changing the parameters accordingly.

The model still binds correctly, however I can't get the file upload to bind to the HttpPostedFileBase.

This binds the model and the file upload:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MapUpdateColumns", "RepositoryAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UpdateDataset", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {%>
```

This only binds the model:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("MapUpdateColumns", "RepositoryAdmin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "columnMappings" }, new { id = "UpdateDataset", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {%>
```

The controller action:

```
public ActionResult MapUpdateColumns(DatasetViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase sourceFile)
```

Should this be possible, and if so what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot upload files with AJAX. One way to achieve this is to use a hidden iframe which will simulate an AJAX call and perform the actual file upload or use Flash. Here's a very nice [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) plugin using a hidden iframe which is capable of transparently ajaxifying a form submission containing file fields.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I used that jQuery Form plugin sometime ago so I should have remembered this myself! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, the answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522052/1067149

I did it myself and it's guaranteed it works.

Answer (score 0):

ADD `id="file"` in your tag input

IN YOUR ACTIONRESULT PARAMETER
HttpPostedFileBase 'file' name and view tag name should be same

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(tbl_products tbl_products,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tbl_products.phototype = file.ContentType;
                tbl_products.photo =new byte[file.ContentLength ];
                file.InputStream.Read(tbl_products.photo,0, file.ContentLength);

                if(obj.insert(tbl_products))
                {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                }   
            }

            return View(tbl_products);
        }
```

IT WORKS FOR ME

Comment: Why are you yelling?

Comment: Sorry my internet was disconnecting continuously i am yelling to answer the mention question

Answer (score -1):

Yes I also agree. You can definately upload files using 'Ajax.BeginForm'.Add 'enctype = "multipart/form-data"' to the AjaxOptions object.