# Auto click/Force trigger js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have in my MVC view..

```
 //Submit file
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) { %>         
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
     <input type="text" id="file-name" name="Id"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
 <% } %>     

//Save link.
 <span class="Update" onclick="js.function()">Update</span>
```

Once I click on the Submit button, I go to controller and the method to run some code that submits the file to the database. After that is finished, I need to auto-click/force click the save link so that the js function is run after the submit .. how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Ajax.BeginForm and in the OnSuccess handler you can click the button. Your code would look something like this (not tested but should lead you in the right direction):

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("MethodName","ControllerName",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        OnSuccess ="OnSuccess",
        OnFailure ="OnFailure" 
    },  
    new { 
        enctype = "multipart/form-data"
    })) { %>         
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
     <input type="text" id="file-name" name="Id"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
 <% } %>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function OnSuccess() {
    $('.Update').trigger('click');
}
```

**Edit**: If you were not trying to upload a file my above answer would be what you want. However, I have looked into this a little more as I noticed you were trying to post a file; and you cannot upload files using ajax without using html 5, iframe hacks, etc. It appears to me that your best bet would be to use an uploader such [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) that resolve this issue using html5, flash, or hacks based on how you set them up.

Also, [binding-httppostedfilebase-using-ajax-beginform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491230/binding-httppostedfilebase-using-ajax-beginform) is a similar question that has something that may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of ways.. You can use the submit button as your trigger, prevent the default from happening with it which would be the standard method of posting. Then invoke a jquery post/get/ajax method instead. From which upon succession of that post/get/ajax run whatever else you want to do.

You could just click the button with jquery if you have something else in mind ie: 
`$('button').trigger('click');`

unfortunately the description you have is a little open ended, so its hard to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically `trigger` a click (or any other event like this, for that matter), you need to first have the event established like so:

```
// setting up the event (in case they actually click it)
$('.Update').on('click', function () {
       test();
});

// this will automatically call it
$('.Update').trigger('click');

// whatever your function is doing
function test () {
    alert('here');
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zj9Gw/1/)
    ​