# Send input tyle file to controller in umbraco

Tags: file, umbraco

I used Ajax.BeginForm to sent form with input type file in umbraco to surfaceController. But I don't have files in FormCollection. It possible send file using ajax?

Comment: Which javascript framework do you use ?
Angular ? JQuery ? KnockoutJs ?

Comment: I've tried this is in the past but came to the conclusion that sending files through ajax simply does not work out of the box. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491230/binding-httppostedfilebase-using-ajax-beginform

Comment: Which version of Umbraco do you use? Why don't you use Umbraco Forms?