# purpose of callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Maybe someone mark my question as duplicate or else but i am confusing about `callback` in `JavaScript`. I read from [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485561/2385565) a following piece of code

```
getText = function(url, callback) // How can I use this callback?
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        callback(request.responseText); // Another callback here
    }
}; 
request.open('GET', url);
request.send();
}
function mycallback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
getText('somephpfile.php', mycallback); //passing mycallback as a method
```

and now if i change the above code and remove `callbacks` like following

```
getText = function(url) //Also remove from here  How can I use this callback?
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        mycallback(request.responseText); //Now here i simply call that function
    }
}; 
request.open('GET', url);
request.send();
}
function mycallback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
getText('somephpfile.php'); //Remove (passing mycallback as a method)
```

So now what is difference now?
If no difference then why use `callbacks`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use callback in JavaScript, what are its advantages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070495/why-use-callback-in-javascript-what-are-its-advantages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now what is difference now? If no difference then why use callbacks

Your first function is more general (reusable). You can do all of these:

```
getText('somephpfile.php', console.log); // or
getText('somephpfile.php', alert); // or
getText('somephpfile.php', mycallback); // or
getText('somephpfile.php', yourcallback); // or
getText('somephpfile.php', whatever);
```

which will behave differently. In your second function, the `getText` cannot be used for anything else but alerting ajax data.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're unclear about? Not having a parameter for the [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) - which is effectively removing the "callback" - is like not having a `return` statement in your function.

Comment: I send a `function` as a `parameter` to call later as a `callback` what if I call actual `function` where I call `callback` and not pass as a `parameter` in a `function`

Comment: That's like putting more code in a normal function, but still having it not `return` results to its caller.