# Examples of efficient use of callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

So I understand that callbacks are essentially functions that are passed into another function and executed at a later time.

I am also aware that a lot of major libraries such as jQuery use callbacks efficiently, but I wanted a simple code example along with an explanation on when it is best to use a callback function to solve a problem. 
All the examples I ve seen so far are the setTimeout, but I wanted to see a fresh example to broaden my mind on how callback functions can be used.

So utimately, I wanted to see 
1. An example of a callback function.
2. Why it would be an appropriate solution/approach in that example.
3. Possibly other common reasons/scenarios for using callbacks.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `other built in functions` - that's a broad stroke there. If the examples you've seen aren't helping, I doubt very much another example will help

Comment: Hmmm good point. Thank you for pointing that out. Let me take that out of the question.
I just wanted to see good examples of callback functions and why it would be appropriate to use it in that context.

Comment: You can read up a bit on `Functional Programming` and how in JS a function can be passed as an argument to another function

Comment: Will be sure to do it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is usually used when you have to deal with a function (or method) which you don't know how much time could take to compute.

For example, assume you need to get some water from a shaft to do something, but you don't actually know where and how far this shaft is from your house: you ask a friend (asynchronous function) to kindly walk to the shaft and take the water for you, so that *when he comes back* you can use it.

In the mean time, *while waiting for the water*, you could have done some other useful things.

A basic example of that would be:

```
function getWater(callback) {
    // Walk to the shaft
    // Take water
    // Go back home 
    // This function is asynchronous

    callback();
}

function useWater() {
    // Do what you needed to do with water
}

getWater(useWater);
// While waiting to use the water:
doUsefulThings();
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. I think I now have a better understanding of when to use callback functions. I guess its a matter of reading and writing more code, as well as reading up on what others have to say about this topic. Anyways, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

functions are first-class objects, we can pass a function as an argument in another function and later execute that passed-in function or even return it to be executed later. This is the essence of using callback functions in JavaScrip
JAVA SCRIPT callbacks

Example:

```
   function test(data,function(datafromfunc){
           //my function
});
```

inside service function

```
  function(data,callback)
{
  //your logic
  callback(result)
}
```

example 2
//JavaScript callback functions

```
function randomize(min, max, callback) {  
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (min - max) + max);
    callback(random);
}

randomize(5, 15, function(rndm) {
    alert(rndm);
});
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070495/why-use-callback-in-javascript-what-are-its-advantages

Comment: Thank you for the example code and a very easy to understand example :)

Comment: Although I do appreciate your answer, I felt like Marco Bonelli's answer provided more clarity. If I could, I would accept both your answers as correct.

Comment: thank you,if you know more,please share

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, we have the ability to treat `Functions` just like any other `variables`.

That is, traditionally we write a function like:

```
function sayHello(name){
      console.log("Hello "+name);
}
```

and then invoke it passing the necessary arguments:

```
sayHello("JavaScript");
```

This is pretty much how we use functions in other scripting languages as well.

But, what if I tell you, that in JavaScript, a `function` is as good as a `variable` in a way that it can be passed as an argument when we invoke the function?

For example:

```
var sayHello = function(name){  // My callback method
  console.log(name);
};

function getNameAndSayHello(callback){
   var name = 'My name is a Sandeep'; // I do some other things here...
   //..........some other code.............
   //..... when i am done with other things, i call the callback method... 
   callback(name);

}

getNameAndSayHello(sayHello);
```

As you will see, I am passing `sayHello`(a function) as an argument to another function `getNameAndSayHello`. In short, essence of `Functional Programming`, although not in the purest form.

This ability to pass `functions` just like any other `variable/value` makes it very convenient for us to invoke the `callback` at a later time which suits us.

http://jsfiddle.net/wz9b1s8m/