# Javascript display blank variable in html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to view source code of current page using Javascript, so I use this snippet code:

```
function getSourceCode() {
var url="http://localhost:8080/java/",xmlhttp;//Remember, same domain
if("XMLHttpRequest" in window)
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if("ActiveXObject" in window)
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert(a);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And in HTML file, I declared a line

to print out the variable stored all source code like it alert to screen. But it always alert to my screen without print to variable "a" in the html screen.

This is my HTMl code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vo Tinh Thuong</title>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="getSourceCode();" />
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to print out the variable to html webpage, not alert it like that.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. When I isolate the printing part, it works

Comment: If you click ok to alert ...it will print variable in webpage...OR comment `alert(a);` line

Comment: But in my case, when I run this code, it only alert but not print out "a" variable to web page.

Comment: I just want to print all "a" variable to my screen in html webpage, not alert.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending an asynchronous request, hence it is unable to print the response. You have to keep the code in a `callback` and pass the response to `callback` from that. You can find the clean explanation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485495/2830834) (or) check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

```
function callBack(a){
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

call this `callBack(a)`

Comment: I just added this function you said and it still can't work.

Comment: add  <script src="code.js"></script> after body instead of head section

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem. If I want to put the "a" variable content "responseText" of source code of current page, I should put it into `textarea` instead `p` tag.