# Javascript onload and onunload

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onunload

Consider the following HTML snippet containing some javascript utilizing `prompt` and `unload`. The `prompt()` method works fine but I want alerting something like **Goodbye, user** when reloading or leaving the page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<body onload="promptName()" >


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function promptName()
        {
            var userName = prompt("What's your name ?", "")
            return userName;
        }

        function goodBye()
        {
            alert("Goodbye, " + promptName() + "!");
        }

        window.onunload = goodBye();

        </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing against? According to the MDN, onbeforeunload behaves differently in different browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should write it like this:

```
window.onunload = goodBye;
```

Also, you might consider using the onbeforeunload event in some browsers:

```
window.onbeforeunload = goodBye;
```

When you write `window.onunload = goodBye();` you assign whatever handler that is returned from `goodBye` to the `unload` event. Since nothing is returned, there will be no event handler. You need to reference the function instead: `window.onunload = goodBye;`

Answer (score 4):

You can't assing  this way:  window.onunload = goodBye();

If you want to assing this way you have three ways:

```
// by this way you use the name of the function, so you override the onunload function with goodBye function
window.onunload = goodBye;
```

or

```
  // This way you redefine the function
    window.onunload = function(){goodBye()};
```

And my favourite because it allows you to add more functionality:

```
// This way you create a event listener which allows you to add as many functions as you ant
window.addEventListener("unload", goodBye, false);
```

Comment: Just a note: The last example will break IE versions below 9.

Comment: `addEventListener` is not avail in IE8-

Comment: what in my example is not available in IE8?

Comment: I’m not sure I can explain it better than my previous comment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="promptName()" >


        <script type="text/javascript">
        function promptName()
        {
            var userName = prompt("What's your name ?", "")
            return userName;
        }



        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert("Goodbye, " + promptName() + "!");
}
        </script>

  </body>
```

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: But it gives goodbye message just after prompting the name; I want this goodbye message after F5 or clicking close icon

Comment: @George see my answer, you should reference the function, not execute it.

Answer (score 1):

As seen [HERE](http://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/window-onbeforeunload-javascript-code/)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert("Goodbye, " + promptName() + "!");
};
```

or

```
window.onbeforeunload = goodBye;
```

Although I would suggest saving the username to a glob by seting a var outside you load func that receives the username after first prompt, then you dont have to prompt them for their name again when they leave

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var userName = ""; 

function promptName()
{
    userName = prompt("What's your name ?", "")
    return userName;
}

function goodBye()
{
   alert("Goodbye, " + userName  + "!");
}

window.onload=promptName();     
window.onbeforeunload = goodBye();
```

Comment: prompt works fine, problem is that I want goodbye message after clicking close button. This code gives goodbye message just after prompt no matter of onunload() or onbeforeunload()

Comment: it was just to show you the event. you have to change your code like this function goodBye()
{
   return ("Goodbye, " + userName  + "!");
}

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but the accepted answer doesn't. This also supports more browser events.

This can also be used together with various `onbeforeunload` and `beforeunload` scripts.

```
var doOnUnload = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var eventType = window.attachEvent ? 'onunload' : 'unload';

doOnUnload(eventType, function(e) 
{
    console.log('godbye');
});
```