# Calling a REST service before leaving the website

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, frontend, video-streaming, html5-video

I am developing a website where I have many videos and want to store all video times in to DB before leaving the website just like NETFLIX. I have written REST service in the below function and this function will store data into my DB. But, i am unable to store the details into DB as website is getting closed as soon as rest service called. Is there any other way where I can achieve this?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {

}
```

Comment: `$(window).unload(function(){ /* do stuff */ });`

Comment: Thank you @StackSlave for the quick response. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Take a look at using [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript onload and onunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907867/javascript-onload-and-onunload)

Comment: @StackSlave Website is getting closed before calling the REST service when i use $(window).unload(function(){ /* do stuff */ });  After closing the website tab, unload function is getting called and console log is printing but after that there is REST service and  it is not getting called.

Comment: you need to Write service call in beforeunload event.check my answer window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) { console.log('I am the 1st one.'); })

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call service then you need to use brforeunload event.unload event only useful for console.log stuff

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
       console.log('I am the 1st one.');
      });
  
     window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
         console.log('I am the 3rd one.');
        });
```

Using jQuery

```
        $(window).unload(function(){
            console.log("Goodbye!");
         });
```

you might consider using the onbeforeunload event in some browsers or you going use to alert then you need use [onbeforeunload][1] event.

Comment: I have used

   $(window).unload(function(){
            console.log("Goodbye!");
         });

and when i did debugging, after closing the site, it stopped at console.log() but after that there is REST service and site is getting closed before calling the REST service.

Comment: you need to Write service call in beforeunload event.check my answer window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
       console.log('I am the 1st one.');
      });

Comment: I have written the service in window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) { console.log('I am the 1st one.'); }); I started debugging before closing the site tab, it is stopping at console statement but its not calling the service, i have checked the DB and java controller, it is not called.