# Ext.Ajax.request with a custom enctype

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm having to communicate with a custom back-end at the moment, which is only accepting an encoding type of "multipart/html". I wanted to see if there was an easy way of submitting data to the server via the Ext.Ajax class but with custom encoding?

I've tried:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  ...
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
})
```

and also

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  ...
  extraParams: {
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
```

Neither of which worked.

Comment: The solution is here.
I found a work arround :)

[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13522052/1067149

Answer (score 0):

Use `headers`: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-headers

Add something like:

```
...
headers: [{ Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data' }]
...
```

Note: I've never used something like this myself. I just looked through `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` source code and found that they use this property to pass it inside the `request()` function. Documentation is somewhat laconic on this - so you might end up trying couple different things.