# File upload with ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, file-upload

I know this has been discussed a lot of times.

I basically want the possibility in my view to update a file. This file has to be mapped to the model the controller expects:

```
public ActionResult Create(Company company)
{
    //Do something with the received model
}
```

The model:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PictureUpload { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This is working without any problems.
Now I'd like to send my form data, including the file, via AJAX.
Therefore I'm using this in my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Company", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "ajaxOnSuccess", OnFailure = "alert('Error message.');" }, new { @class = "ym-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

This is basically working but the file upload doesn't work (as far as I read ajax doesn't have access to the file so it can't be sent).

I'd like what's the best solution for this problem without having to modify my backend (controller/model).

E. g. I read this article:
http://ajeeshms.in/Blog/Article/1/upload-files-using-ajax-in-asp-mvc

It provides two nice possibilities but I'd have to modify the backend because as far as I see the automatically mapping to the HttpPostedFileBase type in my model wouldn't be possible anymore.

I don't mind using any working plugin for my view or using a technique which is supported by new browsers only.

Comment: You can use ajax with html5 file api. [See this post](http://timothypoon.com/blog/2011/05/10/ajax-uploading-with-html5s-file-api/)

Comment: Have a look at my accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440220/how-to-upload-file-in-strong-type-view-in-asp-net-mvc/18441187#18441187

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

//Add reference to form.js

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype ="multipart/form-data",@id="formid" }))
{

}

//Javascript code

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#formid').ajaxForm(function (data) {

});

</script>
```

This will work as ajax submit.

//You can get more details on AjaxForm [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ym-form", enctype="multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: You can try  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create","Company", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {%>
       <input type="file" /><input type ="submit" value="Submit File"/>
   <% } %>

Answer (score 0):

I have made it based on this answer from Demian Flavius:
[How to do a ASP.NET MVC Ajax form post with multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581703/how-to-do-a-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-post-with-multipart-form-data#13522052)

Basically it's the new JavaScript's FormData object that makes it easy for uploading with ajax as in the article your mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot upload files with AJAX. One way to achieve this is to use a hidden iframe. Try this [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) and [Telerik file control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx)

Please refer this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1450881.aspx) also.