# Jquery code not executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file in MVC I have used following jquery code to get file on controller.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            var form = e.target;
            if (form.getAttribute("enctype") === "multipart/form-data") {
                if (form.dataset.ajax) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                            if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                                var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                                if (updateTarget) {
                                    updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send(new FormData(form));
                }
            }
        }, true);
    });
```

I have taken this script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581703/how-to-do-a-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-post-with-multipart-form-data/27545268#27545268)

Its working file but when I want to run some other jquery script thats not firing here the code of that.

```
function OnUserSuccess() {
        if ($("#UserDocumentID").val() == 0) {
            mvcNotify.displayMessage("Record saved successfully.", "success");
        } else {
            mvcNotify.displayMessage("Record updated successfully.", "success");
        }
    }
```

I call it in `Ajax.begin Form()`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DocEdit", "User", new { EditUserID = ViewBag.EditUserID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "UserPartialdiv", OnSuccess = "OnUserSuccess" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-sm" }))
```

I am not much aware of jquery and new to mvc as well please be polite.

Comment: And where are you call `OnUserSuccess`? And when it should be called?

Comment: its in Ajax.begin Form()

"@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DocEdit", "User", new { EditUserID = ViewBag.EditUserID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "UserPartialdiv", OnSuccess = "OnUserSuccess" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-sm" }))"

Comment: There are few things you need to note here **1.** jQuery library was created to ease vanilla javascript syntax, so dont use vanilla JS syntax unless its really required. **2.** jQuery library provides simple yet efficient methods for ajax functionality,http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. also same appplies for event handling as well ,http://api.jquery.com/submit/ .  so use those. **3.** I dont see any references of `OnUserSuccess` in your script

Comment: You write it in wery tricky way. Just a gess - have yo try to comment this 2 lines? `e.preventDefault();` 
                    `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have overridden MVC Ajax submit with your javascript `submit` function, you can try calling the method in your success call back like this

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                            if (form.dataset.ajaxUpdate) {
                                var updateTarget = document.querySelector(form.dataset.ajaxUpdate);
                                if (updateTarget) {
                                    updateTarget.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                                }

                              //Call your method here
                              OnUserSuccess()
                          }
                    }
```

Comment: yes I was missing this thankyou so much u save my day sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the JQuery function, use the

```
var file = new File();
```

After this you must be having the button for upload, on it's click event, get the file.

```
var fileDate = $('#textboxId').value();
```

and send this fileData via ajax call to controller

```
$.ajax(type: "POST",
       url: '\YourController\yourFunctionName',,
       data: { yourParameterNameInControllerFunction : fileData },
       success: function() { alert('Success'); },
       error: function() {alert('Error')});
```

your controller should look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult functionName(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

 if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
 var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/giveyourdirectory"), fileName);
 file.SaveAs(path);
}

 return RedirectToAction("functionName");
}
```

this is the basic requirement needed for the upload.